# Comparison complexity from left to right

Tags: php, algorithm, performance, compare

Years ago, I have been told that *tests should be built as a funnel* : **complexity has to grow from left to right** (to improve performance I think).

For instance, `if ($a == '1')` would be better if written `if ('1' == $a)`, because $a complexity is unknown while '1' is low.

Now I don't remember exactly why this rule exists and can't find anything about it since I can't really express it, apart from [this page](http://wiki.c2.com/?CompareConstantsFromTheLeft) which is a bit shady.

Is this a real thing ? And if so, why ? Please and thank you :)

Comment: What you're presenting has nothing to do with complexity. Your example and the discussion on that page are referring to [Yoda style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).

Comment: Well for 1 thing if you used the assignment operator rather than comparison you'd get an error, rather than reassigning. e.g. `if ($a = '1')` vs. `if ('1' = $a )`

Comment: @El_Vanja that's what I was looking for, Yoda Style.

Comment: @El_Vanja thank you :)